# Symfony3 JsonResponse no status available

Tags: json, ajax, symfony, symfony-3.3

I sending over the Controller an JSON response

```
$response = new JsonResponse($array);
return $response;
```

When I call the controller direct over the browse there is a Status 200, but over an Ajax call Symfony don't receives any status. Here the screen of the debugging toolbar:

[image]

Comment: What is the question? Did you try to update Symfony ? If you really want to know the status code, use your browser DevTools and check the Network tab. If you think it's a bug, post an issue on github.com/symfony/symfony

Comment: How are you calling the URI using AJAX - show us the jQuery code?

Comment: I am calling the ajax call over the function for DataTables: var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "ajax": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/url",

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the AdBlocker. In my URL I had the keyword /advertiser/ and thats why the Adblocker has blocked the request.

Without Adblocker or changing the URL works fine!